# Pass variable from mixin @each loop into @content

Tags: sass

Is it possible to pass a variable from an `@each` loop running inside a `mixin` into the `@content`.

See example below on how I try to use the `$passthis` variable inside the `@content` content.

```
// data formatted as an $key and $value array
$data: (
  a: 'house',
  b: 'electro',
  c: 'techno'
);


// example mixing running a @each loop using passed array
@mixin example($array) {

  // each converting $array into $key and $value for each loop 
  @each $key, $value in $array {

    // turn $value into $passthis var
    $passthis: $value;

    // content which contains $passthis variables 
    @content

  }
}


.music {

  @include example($data) {

    &-#{$passthis} {
      display: none !important;
    }

    &-2-#{$passthis} {
      display: inline !important;
    }

  }
}
```

When I try to use `#{$passthis}` in the example `mixin` I get this error.

```
Undefined variable: "$passthis".
```

Is it impossible to use `@content` this way?

See [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/ab751fffed4f5d3a2361a3ebef7840bf) for live demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform `$passthis` in a global variable using this sintax:

```
$passthis: $value !global;
```

I created a sassmeister: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/36286bdae2bcc6f8b278254b8ec5b205

Comment: Perfect mate, I need to take advantage of this more. Thank you! +1